# How Can I solve for a vector by multiplying the matrix inverse for non invertible matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse, matrix-calculus

I have the following[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N6ogT.png) equation
I need to find {N}
what I did is :
multiply both sides by [X1 X2 ....]'
then I multiply both side by the inverse of the multiplication inv([X1 X2 ....]'[X1 X2 ....])
but I couldn't find the {N} vector. I guess because if  m<n , the matrix  ATA  is not invertible.

is there a way to solve for my {N} vector ?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Assume the matrix has rank $2$, there will be a two-dimensional space of solutions, so you have to use standard techniques of reducing to reduced echelon form and write out the general solution. You can find information in any linear algebra book or on-line.

Comment: The least-squares solution of $x=An\,$ can be expressed in terms of the 
[pseudoinverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse)
$A^+$ and an arbitrary vector $b$ regardless of the shape or rank of $A$
$$ n=A^+x+(I-A^+A)b $$